# how can I have my bash script detect mac filtering

Tags: mac-address, bash

I have my own hacking lab with old computers and routers. I hooked up my tp link mr3040 openwrt router via ethernet and have it as its own router on the network. I thought, "if mac filtering is on, how can I have my router detect it on the ethernet port?" I thought it would be similar using `dmesg | grep "fail"` or `dmesg | grep "assoc"` and look for mac filtering error code, but when I did that it returned 0 results.

I was wondering if anyone knew a way to detect it, or am I somewhere close but not quite there?

edit: openwrt is linux based for embedded devices, mr3040 is currently on Barrier Break 14.07. Not windows.

Comment: MAC filtering applies only to wireless clients (and is irrelevant for your needs), however all packets logged (dmesg or syslog or whatever) contain the MAC addresses of both the source and destination.  replace `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` with the desired MAC address in the following `dmesg | grep " MAC=.\{18\}XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"` or simply `dmesg | grep -i "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"`.  This assumes logging is turned on and at an appropriate level.

Comment: I guess that your router MAC filtering is based on its `dhcpd` config. If my guess is correct, you should look at where `dhcpd` is logging and search for DHCPNACK.

Comment: Codemonk113 are you sure? When i had it enable i didnt have internet access on my tplink. But once i spoofed the mac address on my tp link i had internet.